# C# Entity Framework Multiple Results

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to consume multiple results from a stored procedure, which returns 3 result sets.

- The first result is a single column called 'Message'.
- The second result set is a table
- The third result set is another table

My main problem is that every other example on how to approach multiple result sets from a stored procedure implies that every result set can be mapped to an entity, which is not the case with my first result.

First result:

```
Select @Message
```

Second result set returned from this query:

```
Select SecondId, SecondName 
From T_Table1
```

Third result set returned from this query:

```
Select ThirdId, ThirdName 
From T_Table2
```

**Update**
I'm updating my EDMX directly, I'll include an Example from Microsoft and explain my problem.

```
<FunctionImport Name="s_GetAllData">
      <ReturnType EntitySet="CustomerNames" Type="Collection(Model.CustomerName)" />
      <ReturnType EntitySet="CustomerOrders" Type="Collection(Model.CustomerOrder)" />
      <ReturnType EntitySet="CustomerShippings" Type="Collection(Model.CustomerShipping)" />
</FunctionImport>
```

According to this I'd need a Collection Type to reference (meaning I'd need a existing table within the Database that reflects the columns coming in).

You can't add a Table to EF Model unless it has a Key field, which I don't have in my Results.

Comment: Your first result is still an Entity, with one property defined as something like `public string Message { get; set; }`

Comment: @entropic Check out my update to the Post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use EDMX files and have not touched them in years, but here is an example of how you can consume multiple resultsets from a stored procedure call using POCO.  In the example below the stored procedure dbo.MyProc has two select statements, assume the first select simply selects a string as in your example.

```
using (DbContexts.MyDbContext db = new DbContexts.MyDbContext())
        {
                using (var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    db.Database.Connection.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.MyProc @param1=@param1";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param1", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 1 });

                    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        using (var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext)
                        {
                            List<string> listSTring = objectContext.Translate<string>(rdr).ToList();
                            rdr.NextResult();
                            List<MyClass> listMyClass = objectContext.Translate<MyClass>(rdr).ToList();
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: Couple of Minutes ago I was able to get something working using this method, still thank you, I can mark this as the answer since I don't think most people prefer editing the EDMX directly.